# Hibernate composite key based on view

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a view representing some statistical information with the following columns:

```
Count Month Year
```

I want to map that view to an entity with same fields using Hibernate. It does not look like Hibernate allows you to map entities without primary key, be it a composite key or just a single column.

Here's the class I am trying to map to the view:

```
@Entity @Table(name="UserRegistration")
public class UserRegistration {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int count;

    // Setters and getters omited...    
}
```

How do I declare a composite key on it, including all the columns to make Hibernate happy?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new to Java so this solution may look crude.

Please feel free to offer more elegant one!

That's what the code should look like:

```
// UserRegistrationPk.java file
@Embeddable
public class UserRegistrationPk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }   
}
```

And then

```
// UserRegistration.java file
    @Entity 
@Table(name="UserRegistration")
public class UserRegistration {

    @EmbeddedId private UserRegistrationPk data;

    public UserRegistrationPk getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(UserRegistrationPk data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```